# Median filter in image processing

Tags: java, image-processing

**EDIT: I am not allowed to use any third part library which directly apply median filter to an image.**

I am trying to implement Median filter in Java. I am using    following logic .

```
package com.start;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MedianFilter {
 public static  void main(String ...args) throws  Exception{
     MedianFilter md= new MedianFilter();
     md.applyMedianFilter();
 }

public void applyMedianFilter()  throws  Exception{
    //input image is 256*230
    File ip = new File("G:\\ct.raw");
    File op = new File("G:\\ctoutput.raw");
      FileOutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(op);
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(ip.toPath());
        int[] resultArr = new int[fileContent.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
            resultArr[i] = fileContent[i] & 0xff;
        }
        int[][] pixels = new int[256][230];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 230; j++) {
                pixels[i][j] = resultArr[(j * 230) + i];
            }
        }
        int[] data = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 230; j++) {
                int counter = 0;
                //median filter of size 3*3
                for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
                    for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
                        {
                            data[counter] = pixels[i + k][j + l];
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Arrays.sort(data);
                stream.write(data[4]);
            }
        }
        stream.close();
}

}
```

But  I am not getting expected  output.  Expected output (3rd image)
[image]

Actual Image

[image]

I don`t what causing this image to blur. Is there any other way to implement median filter  using java

Comment: You should use `resultArr[(j*256)+i]` since that’s the width, not 230

Comment: Assuming row-major order, it actually should be `resultArr[i*230 + j]` as the row index `i` needs to skip over 230 columns to get to the next row.  If the data is column-major order, then it should be `resultArr[j*256 + i]` as you will need to skip over 256 rows to get to the next column.  Please either provide the raw data file, or provide insight on the way the input data is structured.  This is required before providing the correct answer, but the culprit is the way you are copying the pixels into the 2D array.